# Populate Picturebox from filenames in XML

Tags: c#

I have an XML file that has students and their associated picture.  How do I populate all the pictureboxes on the web form using these image locations in C#?

```
 <Students>
  <Student>
    <Name> Billy Blue </Name>
    <Grade> 1 </Grade>
    <Sex> Male </Sex>
    <Age> 7 </Age>
    <Picture> c:/School/Students/BillyBlue.png </Picture>
    <Grades>
      <Score>80.5</Score>
      <Score>100.0</Score>
      <Score>70.0</Score>
    </Grades>
  </Student>
```

Im assuming it will be done in a loop like the one shown

```
     public frmClassRoom()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var XmlDoc = XDocument.Load(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("studentFile"));
        cbTeachers.Items.Add(XmlDoc.Root.Element("Classroom").Attribute("ID").Value);
        IEnumerable<XElement> listStudents =
            from XElement in XmlDoc.Root.Elements("Classroom")
            .Where(teacher => teacher.Attribute("ID").Value == "Mrs.S")
            .Elements("Students")
            .Elements("Student")

            select XElement;


        foreach (XElement student in listStudents)
        {



        }


    }
```

Comment: Have you tried any thing? If tried, share.

Comment: What do you mean populate? What exactly is the output you want to be shown?

Comment: For each student, I want to select the image from the string inside the <picture> node and insert in into a picturebox. The final web form will show 28 pictures ( one for each student )

Answer (score 0):

Use xml to linq to get image list

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("studentFile"));

var query = from c in xml.Root.Descendants("Student")
               select c.Element("Picture").Value;

List<string> pictureList = new List<string>();
foreach (string pic in query)
{
    pictureList.Add(pic);
}
```

Then use asp repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater" runat="server" ItemType="System.string">
    <ItemTemplate> 
       <asp:Image ID="Image1" height="32" width="32" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Item %>' /> 
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater
```

in code behind

```
Repeater.DataSource = pictureList;
Repeater.DataBind();
```

Any way you will not see images since this is a web application and you need to put image in web server. You will have to change picture url accordingly.

```
Ex: <Picture> c:/School/Students/BillyBlue.png </Picture> to
<Picture> ~/School/Students/BillyBlue.png </Picture>
```